# How can I convert a date in string format ("April 25, 2018" ) to timestamp in hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala, hue

I've a "date" column with the `string` like `April 25, 2018` which I need to convert into a timestamp value.

I could convert this using Impala Editor with the below query:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(concat(substr(`date`,1,3), ' ', lpad(split_part(`date`, ' ', 2), 3, '0'), ' ', split_part(`date`, ' ', 3)), 'MMM dd, yyyy') as `date` 
from A
```

But when I use a Hive Editor, this query fails with the error:

> " Invalid function 'split_part' "

How can i convert this string to Timestamp in Hive/Hue Editor?

Comment: what should the output look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `from_unixtime` in conjunction with `unix_timestamp`.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(`date`,'MMM dd, yyyy'),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```